# Cómo puedo enviar notificación Android desde firebase función

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications, firebase-messaging

Estoy creando una aplicación en Android, que guarda datos en Firebase y quiero implementar, que cada vez que se inserta un nuevo nodo en `{Emergencia_911}`, se envía una notificación automática, los token estan registrado en `{Usuario_RD911}`.

Tengo este código y lo que hace es que me borra la tabla de usuario_911

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.enviarNotificacion = functions.database.ref('/Emergencia_911/{keyid}')
.onWrite(async (change, context) => {

 const myId = context.params.keyid;
  const id_token = context.params.keyid;

  if (!change.after.val()) {
    return console.log('nose', myId, 'un-followed user', id_token);
  }
  console.log('tines un nuevo siguidor:', 'otroMas', 'for user:', id_token);

  // Get the list of device notification tokens.
  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
      .ref('Usuario_RD911').once('value'); ////tabla donde esyan los token

  // Get the follower profile.
  // const getFollowerProfilePromise = admin.auth().getUser(followerUid);

  // The snapshot to the user's tokens.
  let tokensSnapshot;

  // The array containing all the user's tokens.
  let tokens;

  const results = await Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise]);
  //const results = await Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getFollowerProfilePromise]);
  tokensSnapshot = results[0];
 // const follower = results[1];

  // Check if there are any device tokens.
  if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
    return console.log('No hay tokens de notificación para enviar.');
  }
  console.log('existen', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'este token te a enviado una notificacion.');
 // console.log('Fetched follower profile', follower);

  // Notification details.
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'Tienes un nuevo msj!',
      body: `te a enviado un SOS.`,
     // icon: follower.photoURL
    }
  };

  // Listing all tokens as an array.
  tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
  // Send notifications to all tokens.
  const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  // For each message check if there was an error.
  const tokensToRemove = [];
  response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
    const error = result.error;
    if (error) {
      console.error('error a enviar la notificacion a', tokens[index], error);
      // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
      if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
          error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
        tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
      }
    }
  });
  return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
});
```

Comment: Hola, te aconsejo modifiques el formato de tu pregunta en base  a [ask] y te sugiero primero revises la documentación para implementar FCM https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=es-419   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?hl=es-419

Comment: En mi repo tengo un ejemplo de como usarlo, el ejemplo muestra la creación de una notificación a partir de un valor que cambia en una referencia de firebase https://github.com/gastsail/Google-Cloud-Functions/tree/master/TurnosFCM/functions

Comment: Saludo antut @GastónSaillén  , lo estado intentando con tu código y aun no lo consigo, podría hacer un tuto, estuve buscando por tu canal y no encontré, muchas gracias de todo modo y espero por tu respuesta. (aun seguiré intentando)

Comment: Dale, cuando tenga un tiempito lo veo

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo tengo el siguiente archivo js para envía notificación push al momento de que se cree un nuevo registro dentro de mi nodo de firebase "Shops"

```
 //import firebase functions modules
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    //import admin module
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


    // Listens for new messages added to messages/:pushId
    exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Shops/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

        console.log('Push notification event triggered');

        //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        var valueObject = event.data.val();

        if(valueObject.photoUrl != null) {
          valueObject.photoUrl= "Sent you a photo!";
        }

      // Create a notification
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "¡Nuevo negocio registrado!",
                body: valueObject.name,
                sound: "default"
            },
            data: {  //you can send only notification or only data(or include both) 
                image: valueObject.image,
            }
        };

      //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority
        const options = {
            priority: "high",
            timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
        };


        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotificationsNewShop", payload, options);
    });
```

Espero te sirva